# CodeWarrior xml project files schema?

Tags: xsd, codewarrior

I am looking for a reference describing precisely the XML project file format used by CodeWarrior. I managed to find XSD files for recent versions of Visual C++ ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4sy8216.aspx)), could anyone point me to some equivalent for CodeWarrior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the engineers that worked on CodeWarrior and its IDE for several years, I can tell you that there was no schema or XSD file produced internally.  The tag names and values depended on the specific set of preference panels you happened to have for the linker and compilers that you setup in your project.

If you have a particular configuration of the CW IDE that you want to target, you can do an XML export from that version and look at the results.  The export facility wouldn't omit tags, although if there are list-type controls in the pref panels, those might be omitted if there aren't any items in the lists.

Comment: Another detail I just remembered -- for some panels that didn't have XML code written for them, the export gives you a text-encoded blob of data without any structure.